# Why is this simple Python program not giving the correct output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

The challenge is given below:

> You will be given an array of numbers. You have to sort the odd numbers in ascending order while leaving the even numbers at their original positions.

```
[7, 1]  =>  [1, 7]
[5, 8, 6, 3, 4]  =>  [3, 8, 6, 5, 4]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]  =>  [1, 8, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 2, 9, 0]
```

My code's logic: The function takes a source array (`src_arr`). I create a new array of only the odd numbers and sort them in `odd_arr`. In the for-loop, the if-statement checks each whether each number in `src_arr` is odd and replaces it with a corresponding sorted odd number from the `odd_arr`.

```
def sort_array(src_arr):
    odd_arr = sorted([num for num in src_arr if num%2 != 0])
    i = 0
    for num in src_arr:
        if num%2 != 0:
            src_arr[src_arr.index(num)] = odd_arr[i]
            i += 1
    return src_arr

print(sort_array([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]))
```

The input is `[5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]` and output of this should be `[1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]`. But I keep getting the output which is exactly same as the input. I did a `pdb.trace()` and everything works fine till it comes to the number 1 in the input list, and I cannot figure out why it is not giving the correct output.

Comment: BTW, if you `import numpy as np`, and `a = np.array([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4])`, then try this little two-line magic: `odd = a % 2 != 0; a[odd] = np.sort(a[odd]); print(a)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can even simplify the code a bit by making `odd_arr` an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) on the sorted list of odd numbers, and simply calling `next(odd_arr)` when needed, without manually managing the index:

```
def sort_array(src_arr):
    odd_arr = iter(sorted([num for num in src_arr if num%2 != 0]))
    for idx, num in enumerate(src_arr):
        if num%2 != 0:
            src_arr[idx] = next(odd_arr)
    return src_arr

print(sort_array([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]))

# [1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]
```

Comment: +option: sorting in reverse and using `pop()` :D

Answer (score 2):

You chose to run the `for`-loop on `src_arr` and maintain a manual index `i` over `odd_arr`.

Personally I find it much more straightforward to run the `for`-loop on `odd_arr` and maintain a manual index `i` over `src_arr`.

This is because we want to look at every element of `odd_arr` in order, so a simple straightforward `for`-loop is appropriate; but `src_arr` is the array on which we're skipping elements, so it's easier to maintain our own index `i` and skip the elements we want to skip manually.

```py
def sort_array(src_arr):
    odd_arr = sorted(num for num in src_arr if num % 2 != 0)
    i = 0
    for x in odd_arr:
        while src_arr[i] % 2 == 0:    # skip even numbers in src_arr
            i += 1
        src_arr[i] = x
        i += 1
    return src_arr

print(sort_array([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]))
# [1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the other ways to look is you are changing the original array, so the number 1 has two indexes after you replace 5 with 1

Simply if you have a copy and change the copy while keeping the original array intact will solve your issue

```
def sort_array(src_arr):
    odd_arr = sorted([num for num in src_arr if num%2 != 0])
    new_arr = src_arr[:]
    i = 0
    for num in src_arr:
        if num%2 != 0:
            new_arr[src_arr.index(num)] = odd_arr[i]
            i += 1
    return new_arr

print(sort_array([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]))
```